# How do I remove the indentation and ">" character in quoted text of a reply message?

Tags: thunderbird

I am using Thunderbird 102.10.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.6. When I reply to an email, it quotes the original message but offsets it with an indentation and ">" character. I would like to quote the original message with no indentation, and no special character. I do not have "Compose messages in HTML format" selected. When I view the thread in Gmail, I see ">" character, when I view it in Thunderbird, I see colored "|". My colleagues have complained about the way this disrupts email threads.
[image]

Comment: *"My colleagues have complained about…"* a standard quote method that's been default since the early days of usenet… Sad really.

Comment: Agreed, @Tetsujin. He needs a better class of colleague.

Answer (score 0):

That is a standard way to reply, as commented. However, you can simply turn off quoting of the previous message, or place the reply below the quote. Right-click on a Thunderbird account, and in *Settings*, *Composition & Addressing*, remove the check mark shown below.

[image: Thunderbird reply format]

There are also add-ons to do what you request, [ReFwdFormatter](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/refwdformatter/) (and [Smart Templates](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/smarttemplate4/), if you wish to change appearance of the quote), as [stated in AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173505/how-do-i-make-thunderbirds-reply-format-look-like-outlooks), summarized below.

- Install the two extensions.
- Restart Thunderbird.
- In *ReFwdFormatter* <kbd>Preferences</kbd>, remove check marks for the prefixes.
- If you wish to change the appearance to match Outlook, see the citation above.

Comment: ReFwdFormatter doesn't seem to work with Thunderbird 102.10.0 (64 bit) on Ubuntu Studio